# Creating an extended class of Springframework JdbcTemplate is throwing bean error

Tags: java, spring

i am trying to create and extended class of org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

```
public class CustomJdbcTemplate extends JdbcTemplate
```

I am creating this customJdbcTemplate to do some monitoring functionality while executing the queries.

Now i am getting a compilation error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.myservice.repository.DataRepository required a bean of type 'com.myservice.repository.CustomJdbcTemplate' that could not be found.
Action:

    Consider defining a bean of type 'com.myservice.repository.CustomJdbcTemplate' in your configuration.
```

what is that i am missing here ? Should i add any annotations in my CustomJdbcTemplate class?

Comment: As the error message says, you need to define a bean of type CustomJdbcTemplate. Only beans can be injected in other beans. Just adding a class to your project doesn't define a bean. Use an `@Bean`-annotated method, or classspath-scanning and a `@Component` annotation on your class, or an XML definition... in short, do what you're doing to define all your other beans.

Comment: i added @Component("JdbcTemplateWithMonitor") as it is done in other classes to define bean. This lead to "Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1;" error

Comment: If the constructor has a parameter, then it needs to be annotated with Autowired, and the argument must be a bean, too. Or you need to pass it explicitly by defining the bean using an `@Bean`-annotated method, or using XML. This is standard spring DI stuff. Read the documentation on how beans are defined and injected.